# justify legend enteries in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I wanted to know how I can go about left aligning the legend enteries in my pgfplot.  This is the effect I would like to have:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,bm}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dotted,gray!90}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style={gray!70!black},
            every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
            every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.8pt},
            }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=14cm,height=11cm,
                    grid = both,
                    log ticks with fixed point,
                    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=\,},
                    every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.9},
                    ymin =  -3,
                    %ymax = 7,
                    xmin = 0.1,
                    xmax = 5,
                    title = {},
                    xlabel={\emph{\bfseries{Frequency}}},
                    ylabel={\emph{\bfseries{Test}}},
                    no markers,
                    every axis plot/.append style={very thick},
                    legend style={at={(0,0)},anchor=south west}
                    ]

\addplot+ {rand};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta = 0.3$};
\addplot+ {rand};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta = 0.5$}
\addplot+ {rand};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta = 0.707$};
\addplot+ {rand};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta = 1.0$}
\addplot+ {rand};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta = 2.0$};
\addplot+ {rand};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta = 5.0$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To option in `axis` just add `legend cell align=left,`:

```
\begin{axis}[width=14cm,height=11cm,
                    grid = both,
                    log ticks with fixed point,
                    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=\,},
                    every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.9},
                    ymin =  -3,
                    xmin = 0.1,
                    xmax = 5,
                    title = {},
                    xlabel={\emph{\bfseries{Frequency}}},
                    ylabel={\emph{\bfseries{Test}}},
                    no markers,
                    every axis plot/.append style={very thick},
                    legend style={at={(0,0)},anchor=south west},
                    legend cell align=left,% <-- aded
                    ]
```

As proof:
[image]